# How to get page parameters from Page based on a template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site with a theme.

I now need a custom page, where the user goes to confirm his email address.  In other words, when he signs up, he gets an email, which links him to:

```
MySite.com/confirm
```

I have this much set up and working, by creating a custom page template, then creating a page based on it with the slug "confirm"

But now I need to get the parameters which are being passed to the page.  In other words, the full link is:

MySite.com/confirm.php?key=5

The problem with this is that it breaks the url in that Wordpress is expecting "confirm" not "confirm.php?key=5" so it just gives a 404 error.

The alternative is to put a custom page at the root to process it, but then it loses the theme.

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about only `confirm/?key=5`, without extension? (assumming you have permalinks lie `%postname%`)

Respectively you can do something like mysite.com/?`p`=%post_id%&key=5, it redirects you to your permalink format, while keeping your query params. (`p` for posts, `page_id` for pages)

To prevent bugs, check out this list of a [`reserved keywords`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms)

Comment: The first suggestion works great! (Haven't tried the second yet.)